# Programmatically creating labels for Chart.js in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, chart.js

I am dynamically creating a line graph for a movie. The y axis is a number of values that is collected over the course of the movies length. The length of the movie is known before. My problem is that ChartJs needs meaningful labels. It also puts each label at the same point as a y axis coordinate so I have to have the same amount of labels as points on the y axis.

This is the code I tried to use to programmatically created an array of labels based on the length of the data that I am feeding ChartJS

```
var makeLabels = function(){
    var numberOfSegments = $scope.data.length;
    $scope.labelArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i = numberOfSegments; i++) {
      var label = i * 10;
      var labelString = label.toString();
      $scope.labelArray.push(labelString);

    };
  }
```

Image
[image: y axis min=0 max=100]

this is a graph without all of the y axis data.

Comment: Can you post the image of the chart?

Comment: Added the image there

Comment: Ideally I want to divide the x axis into 10 minute labels but i cant show the data inbetween those minutes without having a label for each

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it do display the way I want to. The function makeLabels() gets the length of the movie and adds a blank "" label for every label that is not a multiple of 10. I removed the grid lines with scaleShowGridLines: false in the ChartJsProvider.setOptions method.

```
    var makeLabels = function(){
    var segments = $scope.movieLength / 1;
    s
    for (var i = 0; i <= segments; i++) {  
    var modulus = i % 10;
    if(modulus === 0){
      $scope.labelsArray.push(i.toString());
    } else { 
      $scope.labelsArray.push("");
    };
  };
```